# Adding merchants/sellers to magento site

Tags: magento-1.9

We have to add sellers/merchants to our site.

It means, through our site, sellers have to sell the products & we have to get commission

from the sellers.

demo example : https://seller.flipkart.com/

If there are 5 sellers , buyer have to see all 5 sellers in checkout page or

related page. Also Buyers have to check the nearest shop to buy the product using pin code or search box. after they selecting nearest store, than products list should display.

IS there any good extension for this. please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are lots of extensions available to serve your purpose
- Google "magento marketplace extension"
- If you are using free extension, then modifications on those free extensions will definitely help you to achieve exactly what you want
- Theming, designs improvements also can be done over those modules
- If you want your customers to search the nearest shop using pin code,

  - http://www.magestore.com/magento-store-locator-extension.html
  - http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-google-maps-store-locator-find-a-store.html
  - https://www.iwdextensions.com/magento-dealer-store-locator.html
- If you're in budget, custom development could also be a good option

Comment: hi,

Thanks a lot

can you please post the list of links here....

Comment: `http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-1.html`

`http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace.html`

`http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/apptha-marketplace.html`

Comment: thanks a lot, i updated the question : Also Buyers have to check the nearest shop to buy the product using pin code or search box. can you please help me which extension supports this....